# Fill missing values in R data frame without losing row names and column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 R dataframes.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA), b = c(10, NA, 2), c = c(NA, NA, 1))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, 3), b = c(NA, 5, NA), c = c(6, NA, NA))
```

Values present in `df1` are `NA` in `df2` and vice versa. Some values are `NA` in both data frames. I want to create a new data frame which has values from `df1` and `df2`, wherever the value is present, without losing column names and row names.

One easy solution I can think of is using a `for` loop.

```
df_merged <- df1

for(i in 1:nrow(df_merged)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df_merged)){
    if(is.na(df_merged[i,j])){
      df_merged[i,j] = df2[i,j]
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, df_merged will be this

```
df_merged
  a  b  c
1 1 10  6
2 2  5 NA
3 3  2  1
```

I know that `for` loops are very slow in R. Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try:

```
df1[is.na(df1)]<-df2[is.na(df1)]
df1
#  a  b  c
#1 1 10  6
#2 2  5 NA
#3 3  2  1
```

Comment: Thank you for such an elegant solution :)